# slapd not launching on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, ldap, openldap

I have a slight problem with the openldap server installed with Mac OS X 10.6.8 (regular, not server). When I launch `slapd` in a terminal, it stops itself after 1 or 2 seconds... I just have the time to see its process... It doesn't seem to crash, because when I specify a log file in the configuration, the log is created, but empty.

However, when I launch it with the debug option, for example `-d 1`,it doesn't fork and stays in the terminal (that's the documented behavior) and it runs normally. I can connect, and so on... Meaning, I presume, that's not a config problem.

Is there something stupid I've forgotten? (btw, I've repaired the authorizations, just in case, but that doesn't change the problem...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know slapd stopped?

Comment: By watching the `slapd.pid` and/or `ps aux | grep slapd` (very fast)

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I found is to use macports to build the latest version of `slapd`, that works just fine...